# Neither JS or Selenium (FF or Chrome) can click a button in a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

I am trying to drive a web portal for my home heating (using python). There used to be an open source library to use it but this was broken when they introduced some complicate JS and they don't provide API keys to normal users.
Selenium has worked fine to log in and get status data, until I got to a modal dialog where js can't see most of the normal functions (e.g. click, dispatchEvent) that I'd like to use on this fragment:

```
<a data-bind="click: updateZoneHeating, visible: currentZone().showZoneActivateBtn" class="button" style="">Activate</a>
```

It is clearly visible and clickable in the selenium rendering (using Chrome or Firefox latest released versions).

In JS in the console, and Selenium, I can find the element, it has the expected outerhtml shown above in both cases so I think I have the right element.

Size reports correctly.

I was expecting to be able, via JS or selenium, to inject a click event to submit the modal dialog.

In my JS attempts to dispatchEvent or click result in `Uncaught TypeError: b.dispatchEvent is not a function` (and similar for click function)

Using Selenium I get a `ElementNotInteractableException`.

I have tried waiting a long time, waiting until "clickable" (timesout), scrolling into view (it is already in view but that didn't work either). I have tried various selectors xpath, css, and (on a different element with the same problem) id too.

I have tried sending a mouse event from Selenium too.

If I try checkVisibility() in JS I get false, but changing visibility, opacity, z-index doesn't change anything and it's perfectly visible and clickable by hand.

Further digging shows the following js libraries are used on the page:

- bootstrap
- jquery-ui
- Application Insights
- localytics
- google analytics
- msviewport

Comment: I have no reason to think that the reason for both JS and selenium methods being blocked is different and at this point I would be happy with nearly any approach that worked! Because the page is behind a log-in I can't share a URL for the page in question. What further information would be useful.

Comment: Have you tried moving the focus to the modal window?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried but I continue to get the same errors.

Comment: I have tried to use JS to give the element focus but that also appears to be a method that can't be applied to the element.  As the click and dispatchEvent functions don't show in the dom inspection either, I am beginning to think that bootstrap.js is doing something wierd-  removing those methods from the dom elements in the modal window.